# why i am getting responseText(From Servlet to javaScript through Ajax) with extra charaters?

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am working in a project. In which i am trying to get username from session created using the following code:-

**GetCurrentUserInfo.java**

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class GetCurrentUserInfo extends HttpServlet
{

    ServletContext contx = null;
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        contx = config.getServletContext();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            OutputStream outer = res.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outer);
            String userName = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
            oos.writeChars(userName);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
        }

        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

**Calling.js**

```
 function getUserInfo()
 {
     var userInfoHttp;
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
         userInfoHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
     }
     else if (window.ActiveXObject)
     {
         userInfoHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
     }
     userInfoHttp.open("POST", "GetCurrentUserInfo", false);
     userInfoHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     userInfoHttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
     {
         if (userInfoHttp.readyState == 4)
         {
             if (userInfoHttp.status == 200)
             {
                 var res = TrimString(userInfoHttp.responseText);
                 alert(res);
             }
         }
     }
     userInfoHttp.send(null);
     isAnnotationUpdate = false;

 }
```

I res i am getting userName with some extra characters like this:- "���w�s�@�s�.�c�o�m"
In actual my userName is s@s.com only.

Answer (score 0):

I think that 2 things can fix your encoding problem

Firstly use the OutputStreamWriter and give it encoding value

```
OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
String userName=(String)req.getSession().getAttribute("username");
writer.write(userName);
writer.flush();
```

and then make sure your response has the correct encoding

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Related article : [Unexpected character when downloading file client side from a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416687/unexpected-character-when-downloading-file-client-side-from-a-servlet)

**UPDATE**

And something else i forgot in original answer. Set the ContentTyoe of the response Object to text/plain because you are actually returning plain text chars

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
```